# Virtual Directory in Tomcat Wont Work

Tags: apache, tomcat, virtual-directory, windows-security

Help!

I am trying to get a virtual directory in Tomcat 6.0 to work.

This had been working for years in connecting a virtual directory to a share on two separate servers on two separate org domains than my own.

Just recently, and at different instances, this virtual directory stopped mapping, specifically saying:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\CFSoft does not exist or is not a readable directory
>     at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4249)
>   ...
>
> INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/callcenter/soft/asho] has not been started

It looks like it has something to do with user permissions, as I used to be able to browse (from windows) to these server shares anonymously, meaning without authentication, and now I can't. All I can guess at is that Tomcat can't get to these shares due to some domain authentication required, however nowhere in the context (virtual directory) mapping can you specify any sort of credentials.

I am certain my syntax is correct on the  mapping:

```
<Context path="/callcenter/soft/aola" docBase="//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/CFSoft" privileged="true" debug="0"></Context>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.